# Error while trying to connect my wireless adapter

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, windows, virtualbox, hardware

I have a laptop with a built-in wireless adapter **"Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter"** through which I can connect to my Home Wi-Fi.
Weirdly, my Kali Linux machine on the Virtual Box only shows an ethernet connection although in my Windows 10 machine I have a wireless connection as I said **with no physical wireless adapter**, only the one that is built-in and coming from the computer (the Realtek).

When I try to add this wireless adapter to my Kali Linux machine (through adding it to a USB device) I get the error added in the picture [image: usb error]

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox doesn't use a direct connection to your hardware. It creates virtual hardware so you can use it on the virtual machine.

The only way it can use a wireless card is if you use an external wireless card and that share that adapter.

Comment: but what is the difference between an external wireless card to internal? they both make the same thing, so you are saying there is no option to connect with my built-in wirless card?

Comment: yes and no. you'll never going to see your builtin adapter in the virtual machine.